# Fill dataset programatically and show data in report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, dataset

I want to fill a dataset with 3 column table and show this data in a Crystal Report. I trued this code:

```
DataSet1 ds = new DataSet1();
DataTable dt = new DataTable("Table1");

dt.Columns.Add("id", typeof(System.Int32));
dt.Columns.Add("division", typeof(System.String));
dt.Columns.Add("district", typeof(System.String));
DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
dr["id"] = 1;
dr["division"] = "Test";
dr["district"] = "Testtest";
dt.Rows.Add(dr);
ds.Tables.Add(dt);

CrystalReport1 myreport = new CrystalReport1();
myreport.SetDataSource(ds);
crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = myreport;
```

This doesn't work, so the data doesn't show in Crystal Reports. What is causing this problem and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing:  `crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();` after setting ReportSource.
Also, if you have some parameters on your report, set them after the line `myreport.SetDataSource(ds);` so the GUI that asks for them isn't shown (unless that's what you want).